# Azure B2C + Facebook OAuth (Site URL and Valid OAuth Redirect URIs)

Tags: azure, oauth, facebook-apps, azure-ad-b2c

I'm following this guide which says to put the tenant name into the "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs" setting:
https://**${your-tenant-name}**.b2clogin.com/**${your-tenant-id}**/oauth2/authresp
so I did, I put my NonProd Azure Tenant which covers my dev/qa/stg environments:
https://mycompanydevtenant.b2clogin.com/mycompanydevtenant/oauth2/authresp

Now in Facebook, I am wondering what i should put as the "Site URL" setting.
My app has 3 different envs which use this 1 tenant. so the site urls are like (this app has the Azure B2C FB and also Google/Apple SingUpSignIn options):
https://mycompanysite-dev.com
https://mycompanysite-qa.com
https://mycompanysite-stg.com

Do I have to create 3 separate Facebook Apps for each env (so only the Site URL is changing, but the OAuth Redirect URI is not)? Or is "Site URL" not really used for anything? like maybe its just used for information purposes, and I can just put anything for it, even my eventual prod website (https://mycompanysite.com). Although I'm skeptical about the latter.  f

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, Site Url is a kind of base URL of the Application. As you have different environments you have to create separate Facebook apps for each environment and specify the Site URL because Facebook needs to be able to confirm that the requests are originating from valid source.

Comment: The reason why I'm a bit skeptical ... My dev accidentally put a different Site Url (a PROD env url) when we starting off testing in DEV env and it still seems to work and sign into FB w/ Azure B2c even though that DEV url is diff than PROD.
I wish it would allow putting into multiple urls in there, similar to the 'Valid OAuth Redirect URIs', so multiple env sites can use the same config. 1 Azure Tenant which supports 3 envs like mine, then needs 1 FB app to attach to the UserFlow... but then i would have 3 if i had to do for each env url... so that means i would have to have 3 sep tenants.

Comment: Yeah, multiple site URLs require separate facebook apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I configured Facebook as an Identity provider:

[image]

When I run the Application (User Flow), I got the **Sign-in Screen** like below:

[image]

> Do I have to create 3 separate Facebook Apps for each env ? Or is "Site URL" not really used for anything?

**Note** that : Site Url is the base URL of the Application. Specify the Site URL because Facebook needs to confirm that the requests are originating from valid source.

- And the domain must be match Redirect URIs in Azure AD B2C.
- As you have different environments you have to create separate Facebook apps for each environment and specify the Site URL.
- Otherwise, try using the same URI for all of your environments if it belongs to the same tenant in the "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs" column.
- For each environment, try modifying the Site URL field to match the URL of your website.

**Reference:**

[azure-docs/facebook-federation.md at main · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/external-identities/facebook-federation.md) by John Flores

Comment: The thing which is also throwing me off...
Lets just focus on just STG env.
You have an app on https://mycompanysite-stg.com 
You can login via FB (+ Google/Apple)... FB asks you to enter this url as the stg Site Url as the 'base url' to match against like you said...
But Azure B2C also allows like a SingleSignOn functionality.
We also have this same B2C popup login via another app in same env (by using same azure info in the JS of pretend https://mycompanysite-stg-site2.com). How can the Site Url cover both urls then? (unless its just the tenant url like ${my-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com ).

Comment: btw above is my actual use-case. I been testing login (at least with regular Email Signup flow) from both apps in that ENV past week. 
Haven't tested FB yet though so not sure what happens.

Comment: Please try the solution in your env and confirm if it works or not.

Comment: I accepted your solution for now. but note that my 4 envs (3 envs in non-prod: dev/qa/stg and our prod env) w/ 4 different urls only needed 2 Azure Tenants and hence 2 FB applications, one for NonProd one for Prod. It did not need 4 FB apps for 4 different Azure Applications (or 4 different Tenants).